# How to validate component composition / "base"-component / rendered root component in React?

Tags: reactjs, inheritance, extend, composition, jsx

It is common knowledge that when we want to "extend" a `<Component>` in React, we don't actually extend its class via inheritance, but use composition to render it with custom `props` inside our "derived" component, like this:

```
class Component extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<div className={ this.props.special_prop }>
              I'm a component!
            </div>);
  }
}

class DerivedComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<Component special_prop='custom value' />);
  }
}
```

So this will create a new type of component `<DerivedComponent>`, which will still render a regular `<Component>`, but with custom values specified via `props`.

My question is, is there some way to validate that `<DerivedComponent>` actually renders a `<Component>` as its root component / that it is "derived" in that sense from `<Component>`?

I'm asking because I'm developing a listing component which will render list item components of numerous types in a list, but even though these list item components will be different types, each one will actually render the same root component, just customized with different `props`.  I'd like to enforce, via `propTypes` or similar, that the `children` passed to the listing component are actually based on that common root-rendered component.

Had React used classical inheritance, it would just be a trivial matter of checking if each list item instance was also an instance of that common component; however, I do not believe that React has the API to query the root-rendered component of a composition.

Is there some way in React to enforce that the `children` are based on a specific root-rendered component?