# How to solve TypeScript typing issue with component composition

Tags: reactjs, typescript

React promotes composition over inheritance, but I

I have a React component in TypeScript that should host certain kinds of React components. For example, let's say I have a `MenuBar` component, and it takes an array of various `MenuBarItem` components it can host as a prop. I want to force all menu bar items to have the same root element structure, so they must be rendering the `MenuBarItem` component at the root.

The problem I have is that, if I was using inheritance, I can achieve this by defining the prop as something like `items: MenuBarItem[]`, but I cannot figure this out how to enforce this with composition.

By using composition, I created `FooMenuBarItem` and `BarMenuBarItem`, and let them render the `MenuBarItem` internally (See below). So, they don't share the common base class that I can use as a type.

How would I solve this typing problem with composition?

```
export class MenuBarItem extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    render() { return /*...*/; }
}
export class FooMenuBarItem extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    render() { return <MenuBarItem>Foo</MenuBarItem>;}
}
export class BarMenuBarItem extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    render() { return <MenuBarItem>Bar</MenuBarItem>;}
}

export interface MenuBarProps {
    items: MenuBarItem[]; // This would only work if I use inheritance to get the common base type!
}
export class MenuBar extends React.Component<MenuBarProps , {}> {
    render() {
        <div>{this.props.menuBarItems}</div>
    }
}
```

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42826548/how-to-validate-component-composition-base-component-rendered-root-compone), but with no answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the short answer is that there is no way to declare the exact type you want (I would be interested to hear otherwise!).

To be honest I would normally just go with:

```
export interface MenuBarProps {
    items: React.ReactNode;
}
```

And rely on consumers of the code to do the sensible thing.

The only other thing I would consider is that perhaps you could use:

```
export interface MenuBarProps {
    items: React.Component<MenuItemProps>;
}
```

This would only make sense if the various different menu item components all shared a set of common props.